# Error in Moving sql database files

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to copy my database mdf and ldf files programmatically and also change their names.
I tried File.Move() and "Alter database mydb modify file ..." and "use master exec sp_detach_db mydb" but i recieve this error "user doesnt have permission to do this action" or other errors like this.
note that i am an administrator user.
please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it will work to rename the database

```
sp_rename 'Test','MyTest','DATABASE'
```

Here Test is your old database name and MyTest is new database name.

And one thing i want to tell you is You can not change the name of your system database name.
and MYDB is system database.

Comment: thanx Sanjay, but before rename i want to copy them and i recieve this error "Access to this path is denied".

Comment: It is because you ma have not detach the database from sql server.   when you want to move your database files then you should have to detach the database

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you do this as an SSIS package. If you're using SSIS 2005 there is a transfer database task that will allow you to do what you're after. If you're using SSIS 2008 then i believe they have renamed this task to Copy Database Task.

Either way it's quite straightforward to sort out.

Thanks,

Simon